# Finding Transfer Function of RL Circuit

Tags: transfer-function, nodal-analysis, mesh-analysis

[image: RL CIRCUIT]

Can anyone help me to find TF of this RL Circuit

Comment: Where is the output? What quantity do you need, voltage or current? Not lastly, what have you tried? Not that it matters anymore, now, since you already have an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert circuit to Laplace (multiply each L by s and then treat like regular impedances) and solve for voltage dropped across that lower right inductance using regular circuits methods.

Edit to answer questions AFTER OP posted his answer (2nd comment below my answer):

Here is what the transformed network looks like,

[image]

The parallel combination of the right two branches is,

$$\frac{(4+4s)(4)}{(4+4s)+4}=\frac{4(1+s)}{(1+s)+1}=\frac{4(1+s)}{s+2}$$

So, the voltage across the right-two branches will be,

$$V(s)\frac{\frac{4(1+s)}{s+2}}{\frac{4(1+s)}{s+2}+4s}=V(s)\frac{\frac{(1+s)}{s+2}}{\frac{(1+s)}{s+2}+s}=V(s)\frac{s+1}{(s+1)+s(s+2)}=V(s)\frac{s+1}{s^2+3s+1}$$

And the voltage across the bottom-right inductor will then be,

$$V_L(s)=V(s)\frac{s+1}{s^2+3s+1}\times\frac{4s}{4s+4}=V(s)\frac{s}{s^2+3s+1}$$

And finally, the transfer function you are after, \$\frac{V_L(s)}{V(s)}\$, will be,

$$\frac{V_L(s)}{V(s)}=\frac{s}{s^2+3s+1}$$

Check my math to make sure.

Comment: Thank u for your comments. I found from this way

Comment: VL(s)/V(s) = s/4s^2+8s+4 is that true ?

Comment: Ok, i edited my answer to show you my approach.  I used voltage division to find the voltage across the right two branches.  Then used voltage division again to find the voltage across the bottom-right inductor.

Comment: Error: \$s^2 +3s+3\$ is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Chu, found it and fixed it.

Comment: Please don't hand out complete solutions to homework questions where the OP has not made a substantial effort to find the solution themselves.

Comment: I didn't until AFTER he commented his result.  He was so close (look above) that it was obvious he just booted some addition.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, Saying something is wrong is not giving a solution. The comment was meant to lead the OP to a solution.

Comment: @Chu My comment was not intended for you, but for relayman357. Our preference here is just to give **hints**, such as indicating which step contains an error after the OP has shown all of their work.